# Remove Duplicate Node of second element using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

I don't have much knowledge on xslt . I am trying to remove some duplicate node from my input xml but the nodes are not exactly duplicate . The PremiseId value is duplicate but the latitude, Longitude, XCoordinate and YCoordinate values are different. If we get such data in our Input xml then we need to pick only that occurrence of XML node which has the latitude, Longitude values . Currently my xslt is only picking up the first occurrence of duplicate PremiseId.

Input XML :-

```
<CoordinateCollectionRes
    xmlns="http://www.nexteraenergy.org/RetrieveCoordinateResponseSchema"
    xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<ResponseParameter>
        <PremiseId>42210111</PremiseId>
        <Latitude>-80.81082</Latitude>
        <Longitude>28.58942</Longitude>
        <Xcoordinate>3913026</Xcoordinate>
        <Ycoordinate>-42817728</Ycoordinate>
    </ResponseParameter>
    <ResponseParameter>
        <PremiseId>59087449</PremiseId>
        <Latitude/>
        <Longitude/>
        <Xcoordinate>0.0</Xcoordinate>
        <Ycoordinate>0.0</Ycoordinate>
    </ResponseParameter>
    <ResponseParameter>
        <PremiseId>60476616</PremiseId>
        <Latitude/>
        <Longitude/>
        <Xcoordinate>0.0</Xcoordinate>
        <Ycoordinate>0.0</Ycoordinate>
    </ResponseParameter>
    <ResponseParameter>
        <PremiseId>60476616</PremiseId>
        <Latitude>-87.36536</Latitude>
        <Longitude>30.391645</Longitude>
        <Xcoordinate>1556955</Xcoordinate>
        <Ycoordinate>-41998772</Ycoordinate>
    </ResponseParameter>
</CoordinateCollectionRes>
```

XSLT :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:ns1="http://www.nexteraenergy.org/RetrieveCoordinateResponseSchema">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <CoordinateCollectionRes xmlns="http://www.nexteraenergy.org/RetrieveCoordinateResponseSchema">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="/ns1:CoordinateCollectionRes/ns1:ResponseParameter" group-by="./ns1:PremiseId">
        <xsl:copy-of select=".[./ns1:PremiseId=current-grouping-key()]"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </CoordinateCollectionRes>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output XML:-

```
<CoordinateCollectionRes    xmlns:ns1="http://www.nexteraenergy.org/RetrieveCoordinateResponseSchema" xmlns="http://www.nexteraenergy.org/RetrieveCoordinateResponseSchema">
<ResponseParameter>
<PremiseId>42210111</PremiseId>
<Latitude>-80.81082</Latitude>
<Longitude>28.58942</Longitude>
<Xcoordinate>3913026</Xcoordinate>
<Ycoordinate>-42817728</Ycoordinate>
</ResponseParameter>
<ResponseParameter>
<PremiseId>59087449</PremiseId>
<Latitude/>
<Longitude/>
<Xcoordinate>0.0</Xcoordinate>
<Ycoordinate>0.0</Ycoordinate>
</ResponseParameter>
<ResponseParameter>
<PremiseId>60476616</PremiseId>
<Latitude/>
<Longitude/>
<Xcoordinate>0.0</Xcoordinate>
<Ycoordinate>0.0</Ycoordinate>
</ResponseParameter>
</CoordinateCollectionRes>
```

Expected Output XML :-

```
<CoordinateCollectionRes    xmlns:ns1="http://www.nexteraenergy.org/RetrieveCoordinateResponseSchema" xmlns="http://www.nexteraenergy.org/RetrieveCoordinateResponseSchema">
<ResponseParameter>
<PremiseId>42210111</PremiseId>
<Latitude>-80.81082</Latitude>
<Longitude>28.58942</Longitude>
<Xcoordinate>3913026</Xcoordinate>
<Ycoordinate>-42817728</Ycoordinate>
</ResponseParameter>
<ResponseParameter>
<PremiseId>59087449</PremiseId>
<Latitude/>
<Longitude/>
<Xcoordinate>0.0</Xcoordinate>
<Ycoordinate>0.0</Ycoordinate>
</ResponseParameter>
<ResponseParameter>
        <PremiseId>60476616</PremiseId>
        <Latitude>-87.36536</Latitude>
        <Longitude>30.391645</Longitude>
        <Xcoordinate>1556955</Xcoordinate>
        <Ycoordinate>-41998772</Ycoordinate>
    </ResponseParameter>
</CoordinateCollectionRes>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.nexteraenergy.org/RetrieveCoordinateResponseSchema"
xpath-default-namespace="http://www.nexteraenergy.org/RetrieveCoordinateResponseSchema">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/CoordinateCollectionRes">
    <CoordinateCollectionRes>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="ResponseParameter" group-by="PremiseId">
            <xsl:copy-of select="(current-group()[string(Latitude|Latitutde)], current-group())[1]" copy-namespaces="no"/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </CoordinateCollectionRes>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFepY

Comment: I get the error " Error parsing input XML: Premature end of file encountered" When I try to use this xslt

Comment: @ShuvraMaitra I included a link to a demo where you you can see it working against the input you posted. The error you quote seems to refer to the XML input, not the XSLT stylesheet. So you're probably using a different input.